# How to stop a periodic function in golang

Tags: go, timer

So I have a function that is called after every 2 seconds. Like this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func doEvery(d time.Duration, f func(time.Time)) {
    for x := range time.Tick(d) {
        f(x)
    }
}

func helloworld(t time.Time) {
    fmt.Printf("%v: Hello, World!\n", t)
}

func main() {
    doEvery(20*time.Millisecond, helloworld)
}
```

Now lets say I no longer want this function to execute after every 2 seconds. Is there a way I can achieve this in golang? Or is there any better way than this to call a periodic function in golang? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation of [`time.Tick()`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Tick) states it cannot be stopped:

> Tick is a convenience wrapper for NewTicker providing access to the ticking channel only. While Tick is **useful for clients that have no need to shut down the Ticker**, be aware that without a way to shut it down the underlying Ticker cannot be recovered by the garbage collector; it "leaks".

If you need to stop it, use [`time.NewTicker()`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#NewTicker) instead. Run `doEvery()` in a new goroutine, and pass a channel to it which gives you a mean to stop it, e.g. by closing the channel:

```
func doEvery(d time.Duration, done chan bool, f func(time.Time)) {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(d)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for {
        select {
        case <-done:
            fmt.Println("Done!")
            return
        case t := <-ticker.C:
            f(t)
        }
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
done := make(chan bool)
go doEvery(300*time.Millisecond, done, helloworld)

time.Sleep(time.Second)
close(done)

time.Sleep(time.Second)
fmt.Println("Quitting")
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/RgwvJy-rcu1)):

```
2009-11-10 23:00:00.3 +0000 UTC m=+0.300000001: Hello, World!
2009-11-10 23:00:00.6 +0000 UTC m=+0.600000001: Hello, World!
2009-11-10 23:00:00.9 +0000 UTC m=+0.900000001: Hello, World!
Done!
Quitting
```

Comment: That is actually a very clever to do what I wanted to do. Never thought of using channels to stop the execution of a periodic function. Thank you so much man!

Comment: You'll find channels work equally well to communicate state between goroutines generally and is a very common pattern, so study this example well and try to apply it to future Go programming

Comment: @DanielFarrell sure I will. This example just showed us the power of channels and goroutines.